# Uninitialized instance variable takes local variable value (same name) java

Tags: java, variables, initialization, instance, local

```
public class Window
{
protected int size;
public Window()
{
size=1;
System.out.println("Window size="+size);
}
public Window(int size)
{
this.size=size;
System.out.println("Window size="+size);
}
public void setSize(int x)
{size += x;}
public void printSize()
{System.out.println("Size=" + size);}
}

public class RunWindow
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
Window w1=new Window();
Window w2=new Window(2);
System.out.println(w1.size);
System.out.println(w2.size);
}
}
```

Can someone explain me how an uninitialized variable functions when it has the same name as a local variable inside a constructor without arguments and the local variable is only initialized? I noticed that when i run the example bellow the uninitialized instance variable takes local variable's value when i print w1 object's size value inside main.
And another question. Does this change if this happens inside a method and not inside a constructor?
Thanks in advance. I am new in java so be gentle.

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: It is indented...my English are not so good so if you can explain

Comment: Your code is all at one indent level, not in accordance with the Java coding conventions. The request to indent your code was to fix that, which you have not done. Your code here does not illustrate "the local variable is only initialized" nor "the uninitialized instance variable takes local variable's value". In every case the instance variable in your code is initialized. You also do not show the outputs, nor what you expected, nor explain how they differ. What your code does show is initialization of the member variable.

Comment: My question was answered bellow. I can add the output but i hadn't understood the difference between the local variable and the instance variable definition. So my  header is wrong and the understanding of the code also. I can delete the whole question but then i will have a problem with the account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your confusion comes from this piece of code:

```
public Window()
{
    size=1; //this call changes your Windows member variable!
            //it is identical to this.size = 1;
}
```

The 'size' here is not a local variable. You never defined one.

Instead, it is the Windows member variable!

The this.size in the other function is only necessary because of the name conflict.
When there is no local variable 'overriding', than the 'this.' can(and  normally will) be omitted.

Comment: I removed the two system.out.println because i put them there to see the difference. Is the variable size inside the constructor a local variable?

Comment: You are right! I hadn't understood the difference between class member variables and local variables.